# ANTLR GOTO statement

Tags: c++, antlr, goto, labeled-statements

I'am working on simple parser for code:

```
DEF Test( )

a = false
b = false
c = false

IF a THEN
  GOTO LabelA
ENDIF

IF b THEN
  GOTO LabelB
ENDIF

IF c THEN
  GOTO LabelC
ENDIF

GOTO LabelD

LabelA:
$OUT[1]=TRUE

LabelB:
$OUT[2]=TRUE

LabelC:
$OUT[3]=TRUE

LabelD:
$OUT[4]=TRUE

END
```

For now I am able to write a visitor and evaluate **IF** statement.
But my goal is to be able to execute **GOTO** and **Label** statements.
Unfortunately I could not find any similar solution for C++.
Does anybody could give me a tip how to make **GOTO** statement in the ANTLR visitor?
Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: There exist other better solutions certainly, but `goto` is a valid C++ instruction. So, what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I am writing parser for existing language and I want to be able go through tree build for the program, execute statements etc... This is KRL programming language and for this language there is no other parser or compilator available. I am trying to write compiler for this language. To finish this task I need to do GOTO.

Comment: Are you trying to write a compiler or an interpreter? For a compiler, you should not evaluate anything in your visitor. For an interpreter you probably still don't want to evaluate anything in your visitor, but generate some form of bytecode instead and evaluate that. Implementing goto in an AST-walking interpreter is actually kind of difficult/annoying (especially if you can jump into ifs, loops etc. like you can in C for example), so I think you'd have an easier time with a bytecode interpreter.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am trying to write an interpreter. I will check bytecode interpreter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with two passes through the tree. On the first pass, collect a list of nodes that correspond to a label. On the second pass, do a tree walk to interpret a statement. This idealized machine has an IP aka "instruction pointer" for a node in the tree of a statement. Most statements are trivial to execute, altering the state of variables, and where the next IP is the next tree node to execute. However, when you visit a goto statement, you will need to adjust the IP to the new node corresponding to the label. In addition to the IP register of this idealized machine, you will need to represent variables, arrays, and basic types. You would need to think about how to find the tree node for the next statement. It isn't clear if you also want to define procedures. If so, you will also need a call stack. If you intend to represent the program as bytecode as opposed to a parse tree, you are writing a translator aka compiler and a virtual machine. As it looks like you new to this, and it's for a small project, I would just recommend you interpret the tree as is. This problem would be something you would see in a first-term compiler course.

Answer (score 0):

your suggestion to walk through tree twice was the simplest and the best idea. In my parser I do even more. I walk through my tree so many times as I wish, every time when I have goto statement. This can cause infinite loop but this is another question if the parsed program is written well. This is not the best solution but perfect for my issue. Thank you all very much for a help.

Comment: It can only cause an infinite loop if the program you're interpreting actually contains an infinite loop, right? I wouldn't consider that a problem - that's how interpreters are supposed to work. What worries me more is that, if I understood what you're doing correctly, you re-walk the tree to find the label each time you execute a goto, right? So that'd turn goto in an O(n) operation, which will kill performance (though of course I don't know what you need this for, so maybe that's okay).

Comment: I also worry you might have underestimated the "You would need to think about how to find the tree node for the next statement." part of kaby's answer (which admittedly is a bit understated). Are you sure your interpreter will work correctly if you have a label inside an `IF`, for example? I can see a couple of ways, one could easily introduce bugs there when implementing GOTO this way.